# C++ iterator conundrum

Tags: c++, iterator

The output of the program below is

```
1: foo strlen: 3
2:  strlen: 0
3: foo strlen: 3
4: foo strlen: 3
5:  strlen: 0
6:  strlen: 0
```

I don't understand

- why `1` prints the string, but `2` does not and
- what the difference between the three loops is

The source:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    map<string, string> m;
    m["foo"] = "bar";

    const char * s;

    for(map<string, string>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
    {
        pair<string, string> kvPair = *it;
        s = kvPair.first.c_str();
        printf("1: %s strlen: %d\n", s, strlen(s));
        break;
    }
    printf("2: %s strlen: %d\n", s, strlen(s));

    for(map<string, string>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
    {
        s = (*it).first.c_str();
        printf("3: %s strlen: %d\n", s, strlen(s));
        break;
    }
    printf("4: %s strlen: %d\n", s, strlen(s));

    for(map<string, string>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
    {
        s = ((pair<string, string>) (*it)).first.c_str();
        printf("5: %s strlen: %d\n", s, strlen(s));
        break;
    }
    printf("6: %s strlen: %d\n", s, strlen(s));

    return 0;
}
```

**Update** An explanation for programmers with little C++ background would be appreciated.

Comment: Nitpick>: "stdafx.h", missing <cstdio>, missing `std::`. ;-)

Comment: Isn't `kvPair.first.c_str()` temporary?

Comment: Just like `kvPair` from where it came.

Comment: @DevSolar Would you care to explain your first comment for those of us (i.e. me) who do not understand what you are picking at?

Comment: @DevSolar: It's safe to assume that `<cstdio>` is included in `"stdafx.h"`, and he has `using namespace std;`, so `std::` is not necessary.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy: "stdafx.h" is specific to Visual Studio. While the contents of `<map>` and `<string>` are well-defined, "stdafx.h" might contain anything. And `using namespace` is generally frowned at. This was tongue-in-cheek commenting on minor details of coding style; no offense intended.

Comment: @DevSolar No worries, as a C++ novice I'm thankful for any helpful advice.

Comment: @DevSolar `kvPair.first.c_str()` is a temporary.  Of type `char const*`.  (The return value of a function is always a temporary, unless it is a reference.)  Where it points to is to data in the named value `kvPair`.  Which is not a temporary, but which does have block scope.

Comment: @DevSolar `_tmain` is also a Microsoftism.  As is `_TCHAR`.  The start-up function in C++ should be `int main()` or `int main(int, char**)`.  Anything else is implementation specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partially by chance.

In 1/2 you create a local variable within the loop, *copying* the value
out of the map into `kvPair`.  You set `s` to point to data in this
copy.  The copy is destroyed (destructor called) when you exit the
block.  By any means: `break`, `goto`, an exception, or simply finishing
the loop body and going through it again—each time through the
loop, you get a new `kvPair`, which is destructed at the end of the loop
body.  `s` points to data inside `kvPair.first`, and any use of `s`
(even simply copying it) after `kvPair` has been destructed is undefined
behavior.  Anything can happen, and what happens is likely to be
different depending on the level of debug checking and optimization, or
even depending on totally unrelated aspects of the program.  (If you
consistently get an empty string, there is probably some poorly designed
debug checking going on.  Well designed debug checking would cause an
immediate crash, so you would see the error.)

In 2/3, you initialize `s` with the actual contents of the map, so it is
valid until the map is destructed, or the element is removed from the
map.

In 4/5, you create a temporary: `T( initialization )` constructs a
temporary of type `T`, using the initialization given, for any type `T`,
including type `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`.  (This isn't quite
true; if `T` is a reference, for example, the behavior is different.)
And you initialize `s` to point to data within this temporary.  The
lifetime of a temporary is only to the end of the full expression which
contains it, so the contents of `s` become invalid at the semicolon
ending the statement (which in this case is the end of the full
expression).  As in 1/2, undefined behavior ensues when you use `s`
after this.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, storing `*it` in a local variable, rather than using it directly a la `(*it)`, will create 1) an instance of pair, and 2) full copies (rather than just pointers) of the 2 member strings, `first` and `second`. Finally, the `c_str()` method does **not** create anything new, but just returns the pointer to something in the string it was called on, which will be an invalid pointer, as soon as the string gets invalid. Is that about right?

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy Almost.  In general, C++ uses _value_ semantics; new variables, temporaries, etc. are _copies_ of the original, and two objects are totally distinct.  (The exception is when using references.)  But `c_str()` _does_ create a new object.  An object of type `char const*`, however; in C++, pointers are objects.

Comment: So c_str() creates a new pointer, but it's a pointer to some place in the string value, which gets reclaimed once it runs out of scope.  I guess I need to get used to the fact that variant 1 copies the pair, whereas variant 2 does not and accesses the map's pair directly (if I'm assuming correctly here). Then it would all make sense to me.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovksy That's basically it.

Answer (score 5):

In your first example, you call `c_str()` on `kvPair` which is declared in the scope of the `for`-loop. The result becomes invalid when the `for` loop is exited, because `kvPair` is destroyed.

In the second example, you call `c_str()` on the value in the map. The result only becomes invalid when the map is destroyed, which happens when `_tmain(...)` returns.

In you third example, you call `c_str()` on a temporary (created by the cast to pair), and that temporary is destroyed before `printf("5...` is called.

**Explanation**

The pointer returned by `c_str()` points to some memory owned by the `string` it is called on, so when that `string` is destroyed, accessing the pointer is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Would you care to break down what is happening (for C++ learners)? Because even if `kvPair` is temporary (because it is declared inside the for loop?) why would the result of `kvPair.first.c_str()` be temporary, when stored in `s`, which is declared outside of the for loop?

Comment: While it's clear what you mean, in C++ parlance, `kvPair` is not a temporary; the term "temporary" is reserved for unnamed objects destructed at the end of the full expression (like the one he uses in the third loop).

Answer (score 0):

The first loop `s` is pointing to data in the pair - the pair goes out of scope after the loop, so your data is bogus

The second and third loops have `s` is pointing to data in the actual collection - so it stays in scope

Comment: The third loop has `s` pointing to a temporary, which is destructed at the end of the full expression.